# AWS Config not showing full list of non-compliant resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-config

I have created AWS Config for SNS topic not encrypted with AWS KMS. Both SNS and AWS config are in the same region.

I have created 2 sample SNS topics but I can see only one in AWS Config.

AWS config Image:
[image]

[image]

SNS topics created:
[image]

Can anyone explain why the 2nd topic is not showing in AWS Config even though neither is encrypted with KMS?

Regards,

Comment: there is a `non-compliant` filter added on the first screenshot????

Comment: Atleast in ALL filter it should show 2nd topic  which is attached in 2nd screenshot but don,t know why it is not showing

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking it with CLI, because sometimes AWS UI works wonders and it just does not show it in the UI, but it is actually there. Either use boto3 for that or CLoudShell. For CloudShell [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/describe-compliance-by-resource.html) is the documentation and for boto3 it is [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/config.html#ConfigService.Client.describe_compliance_by_resource).